# Laravel: Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Tags: php, mysql

Here is the code which causes problem

```
$parentdata=DB::table('guardians')
                ->where('guardians.ward_id','=',$studentid)
                ->select(DB::raw('concat(father_first_name,father_last_name) as fathername'),DB::raw('concat(mother_first_name,mother_last_name) as mothernamename'))
                ->first();
            
                if(count($parentdata) > 0){
                foreach($StudentsData  as $items){
                $items->fathername=$parentdata->fathername;
                $items->mother=$parentdata->mothernamename;
                }
                }
                else
                {
                foreach($StudentsData  as $items){
                $items->fathername='Na';
                $items->mother='Na';
                }
                }
```

Its showing null when i dd the variable

Comment: What is `$StudentsData`?

Comment: $StudentsData not causing the problem , just if(count($parentdata) > 0) has producing the error.

Comment: Ah, true. `$parentdata` is a single object, not an array (and therefore can't be `count()`ed) because you've called `->first();`. Check if `$parentdata != null`

Comment: yes its null now

Comment: Query Solved Successfully.